# Dynamic text in elementor static page

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am using elementor pro to build a landing page. This landing page will be delivered to a client who will not have access to elementor editor. So I would like to insert some dynamic text so that he can edit some headings of the static page. I thought I could take, in some way, the text of a specific post and "link" it to the text of the heading. My problem now is: the dynamic tags of elementor pro regarding the posts don't have a selectable field that allows me to do this; are there other methods to get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way is to use Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

It lets you create custom fields that you can show on specific pages.

For example in your case you could create custom fields with text editor and then use Elementor Pro's ACF integration to show the text from those fields.

Add ACF field group:
[Adding fields to Posts](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-posts/)

In locations just select page equals to and then select the page you want to show the fields in.

Elementor with ACF tutorial:

[Elementor Integration With ACF](https://elementor.com/help/elementor-acf/)

[How to use Elementor with ACF Tutorial](https://elementor.com/academy/how-to-use-elementor-with-acf-tutorial/)